# bash create a funtion that takes a name as argument and increments the result

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a function for example like if I type a function called myfunc arsenal1 I get the output as arsenal1_2

Comment: What have you tried yet? Share some code with us

Comment: Give us some examples how you script should work. Did the parameter name always ends with an number? And please format you post (the code). Thanks

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? For example, why does incrementing "arsenal1" not result in "arsenal2"? What does "increment" mean? What are its rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

increment() {
    n=`echo "$1" | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]+)$/\1/'`
    echo "$1_$((n+1))"
}

increment arsenal1
increment arsenal09
increment 10arsenal1
```

Output:

```
arsenal1_2
arsenal09_10
10arsenal1_2
```

Comment: Your regex only works if the number is at the end. If your test your code with "increment 10arsenal1"  and "increment arsenal09" you see what i mean. But you code base is good. That is also because the requirements are vague.